# How can I update an entity instead of inserting it into database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

For example, I have a Job entity and a worker entity.
when I add new job I want to assign workers to it but instead of adding it's users to 
the database again ( and create duplicates ) I want to just update workers 
( add jobs to them when I create a new job with worker list )

example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Job{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Worker> workers;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "workers")
public class User extends DataAudit {

  @Id
  private Long id;


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Job job;

}
```

---

```
Worker worker1 = workerService.getWorkerById(1);
Job job = new Job(1,worker1)
jobRepo.save(job)
```

Comment: So you want to assign the same worker to different jobs, you'll need to have ManyToMany relationship or use JonTable, but even in such a case a join table will be updated in your scenario,

Comment: so it won't cause duplicate problem?

Comment: Yes, as you will be updating foreign keys in the join table only

Answer (score 0):

The entities should be using bidirectional OneToMany association with @JoinTable:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Job{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;


  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name="job_workers", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="job_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="worker_id")}
  )
  @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Worker> workers;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "workers")
public class User extends DataAudit {

  @Id
  private Long id;


  @ManyToOne
  @JoinTable(name="job_workers", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="worker_id", insertable=false,updatable=false)},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="job_id", insertable=false,updatable=false)})
  private Job job;

}
```